# How to increment a JavaScript date given a unit (hours, days, months, years), and an amount?

Tags: javascript

Given a date, a unit (days, months, years - heck - even seconds), and an amount, what's the best way to increment a JavaScript date in the cleanest/simplest way possible? (preferably without using a library)

```
var dateIncrementUnit = "d";
var dateIncrementAmount = 1;
var myDate = new Date();

var newDate = ? // myDate + 1d
```

Comment: Have you looked at `momentjs`?

Comment: Using getUnit and setUnit

Comment: @trincot I would like to avoid using a library, if possible without a whole load of if/else statements.

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel Question updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this function:

```js
function addToDate(dt, unit, num) {
    const p = {
        s: dt.getSeconds(),
        m: dt.getMinutes(),
        h: dt.getHours(),
        d: dt.getDate(),
        M: dt.getMonth(),
        y: dt.getFullYear()
    };
    p[unit] += num;
    dt = new Date(p.y, p.M, p.d, p.h, p.m, p.s);
    // Overshooting the end of the month? Return last day of that month
    if ("My".includes(unit) && dt.getMonth() !== p.M % 12) dt.setDate(0);
    return dt;
}

// Example call: add 1 month to today
console.log(addToDate(new Date(), "M", 1).toString());
```

The `if` condition is there to deal with situations where you want to add 1 month to 31 January, which would be like 31 February, but that will be silently converted to 3 March, which would be an odd result. The `if` block ensures that the last day of the targeted month is returned. So 28 (or 29) February in this example case.

Similarly, adding one year to 29 February (when it is a leap year), would give 1 March, while 28 February would probably be the expected answer.

Comment: Not sure what's happening but I get "Invalid date" on logging the date.

Comment: Which three arguments did you pass to the function to get that error? Are you sure you provided a valid date, and one of the acceptable units (y, M, d, h, m, s) and that the third argument is numeric? I can only reproduce this error when the first argument is not a valid date or the third argument is not an integer...

Comment: You're right. Date I was passing wasn't valid. It was a firestore Timestamp object (which can easily be converted to a JS object with `toDate()`.

Answer (score 1):

This function sets the unit of the date to itself + the increment.

```js
function iD(date, increment, unit) {
    var units = {
        s: [date.getSeconds(), "setSeconds"],
        m: [date.getMinutes(), "setMinutes"],
        h: [date.getHours(), "setHours"],
        d: [date.getDate(), "setDate"],
        M: [date.getMonth(), "setMonth"],
        y: [date.getFullYear(), "setFullYear"]
    }
    date[units[unit][1]](units[unit][0] + increment);
    return date;
}
console.log(iD(new Date(), 2, "M") + "");
console.log(iD(new Date(), 3, "y") + "");
console.log(iD(new Date(), 30, "m") + "")
```